# Don't understand the concept of a context in Java EE

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, architecture

Ive been learning Spring, JSP and servlets. I don't understand the concept of a context root. There are so many of them. SpringContext root, servlet context root and there may be others.

In a Spring MVC application, how many context roots are there and how to identify them? What do they really mean?

Comment: You may want to start small with writing a simple servlets application first. You need to understand that world thoroughly - all the rest is built on that.

Comment: This question cannot be given a concise answer that fits within the SO guidelines.  It really requires a tutorial on servlets, which is available elsewhere.  I second @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: go through the servlets tutorial on Oracle's Java website.

Comment: Its surprising that there is that much prereq knowledge required to learn a framework. I dont see why creating a servlets application is important for the question i asked. I already know the role of a dispatcher servlet, front controller. IOC i understand thoroughly. Cant someone explain conceptually what is meant by a context root. Im sure ill understand. Try explaining

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen is right. As an answer to your Spring MVC related question, I hope my following answer will shed at least some light (start reading from the section "**Long Answer**"): [Spring: namespace vs contextConfigLocation init parameters in web.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15825207/814702). And as was already recommended by others, read some basic tutorials first, like the popular: [Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

Comment: How can you understand a dispatcher servlet thoroughly if you do not understand context roots?

Comment: Is it important? I'm a developer not a java programmer. Things should be more straight forward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A context usually refers to the interface used to interact with your runtime environment. This one provides to your program a set of features (like security, request handling, etc...) usually needed by all application running in this kind of domain. Such an environment is generally named `container` in the java stack (servlet container, ejb one, etc...)

See [What exactly is a Context in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918083/what-exactly-is-a-context-in-java)

The term root can then be used when there are different context set up for a single application with inheritance between them. The one at the root hierarchy (usually holding some general configuration) is the root context .

See JB Nizet answer here : [Web-application context/ root application context and transaction manager setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227657/web-application-context-root-application-context-and-transaction-manager-setup)

However in your case the term root has a peculiar signification as it's used for a web container. It refers mainly to the root of the web application path, as there is only one context per web-app we are talking about the `context root` of a given web-app.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html