# context:component-scan in both applicationContext.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I created a servlet filter which is using some Autowired fields. For making it work I declared it as `DelegatingFilterProxy` in web.xml . Before this filter, my enitre spring config was in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` but for some reason declaring bean for this filter was not working in dispacher-servlet. So, I declared it in `applicationContext.xml`. It started working then but Autwired fields inside filter were then throwing `null`. To tackle with it I moved

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproj.abc" />
```

to applicationContext, filter started working then but url paths defined by my controller classes are no longer mapped. So I need to pull following two lines also in applicationContext

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />    
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

This solves the issue. But I was wondering is this the right place for all this code? Because Spring security and for static resources and view mapping all these code goes in dispatcher. In one of my other project I faced same issue and there I did like this, declared only following line in applicationContext

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproj.abc" />
```

And in dispatcher-servlet I change component scan package to controller only and kept all other code there only(in dispatcher)

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproj.abc.controller" />
```

Could anyone please enlighten me on this confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Some terminology: [**`ServletContext`** is the class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). **Servlet context** is the Spring `ApplicationContext` for the `DispatcherServlet`. **Application context**, also know as **root context** is the `ApplicationContext` loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and stored in the web application's `ServletContext`. It is therefore available to other web application components.

The servlet context is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. The `DispatcherServlet` retrieves the application context from the `ServletContext` and uses it as the parent of the servlet context.

A servlet `Filter` is web application component that has no relation to the `DispatcherServlet`, ie. it doesn't know about the servlet context.

The javadoc for [`DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) states

> Supports a "targetBeanName" filter init-param in web.xml, specifying
>   the name of the target bean in the Spring application context.

So the `Filter` bean has to be declared in the application context, not the servlet context.

Put all beans that have application scope in the application context.

Put all beans that have relevance to the MVC stack in the servlet context.

Your `component-scan` should scan the appropriate packages to support the two rules/suggestions above.

Further reading:

- [What is the difference between ApplicationContext and WebApplicationContext in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s)
- [Web-application context/ root application context and transaction manager setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227657/web-application-context-root-application-context-and-transaction-manager-setup)
- [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)

Comment: Thanks it cleared some of my doubts. But where exactly should I put `component-scan` because as I mentioned if I out `component-scan` in `applicationContext` then it does not map my urls of controllers and if I put it in dispatcher then my `Filter` gets deprived of autowiring

Comment: @Abhi Don't think of it as _where do I put my `component-scan`_. Both context might have `component-scan` elements. Follow the guidelines I've set out in my answer. If that means moving your classes to different packages, so be it. Obviously, I can't tell you specifically what to change, you haven't shown us your contexts. Just note that a `component-scan` goes through packages recursively.