# unable to autowire sessionfactory bean in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have searched for various solutions but nothing helping me.

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.oodles.app.dao.impl.RoleDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- spring security config ends here -->

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

  <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
       username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!--
     <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/> 
    -->

     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/> 

  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.oodles.app.domain</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</value>
      <value>hibernate.show_sql=true</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

  <!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/test.jsp -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

  <!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.oodles.app.aspectj , com.oodles.app.domain, 
                                com.oodles.app.dao, com.oodles.app.controller, 
                                com.oodles.app.services, com.oodles.app.dao.impl,
                                com.oodles.app.services.impl" />

   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.oodles.app.aspectj , com.oodles.app.domain, 
                                com.oodles.app.dao, com.oodles.app.controller, 
                                com.oodles.app.services, com.oodles.app.dao.impl,
                                com.oodles.app.services.impl" />

    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login 
            login-page='/login' 
            default-target-url="/" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="j_username"
            password-parameter="j_password" />
      </http>

    <!-- <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager> -->


    <authentication-manager>  
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">  
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext">  
        </password-encoder></authentication-provider>  
    </authentication-manager> 

</beans:beans>
```

RoleDAO.java

```
package com.oodles.app.dao;

import com.oodles.app.domain.Role;

public interface RoleDAO
{
    public Role getRole(int id);
}
```

RoleDAOImpl.java

```
package com.oodles.app.dao.impl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.oodles.app.dao.RoleDAO;
import com.oodles.app.domain.Role;

@Repository(value="roleDao")
public class RoleDAOImpl implements RoleDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Role getRole(int id) {
        Role role = (Role) getCurrentSession().load(Role.class, id);
        return role;
    }
}
```

I also tried with adding @Qualifier("sessionFactory") with @Autowired in RoleDAOImpl. But it didnt worked.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you are bootstraping Spring in the Servlet container.

In web.xml you are creating a root application context out of `spring-security.xml` and also a web application context out of `servlet-context.xml`.

The issue is that beans present in the web application context are not visible to beans in the root application context.

There are multiple solutions to the problem you have, one of which would be to move your Database related configuration into the root application context. Your web.xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Loads Root application context -->
    <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- spring security config ends here -->

</web-app>
```

I have renamed `spring-security.xml` to `applicationContext.xml` and it contains the code that your `spring-security.xml` contained plus the extra following code (that is moved from `servlet-context.xml`):

```
<!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
       username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!--
     <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/> 
    -->

     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/> 

  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.oodles.app.domain</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</value>
      <value>hibernate.show_sql=true</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I am getting this error: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Comment: Thanks @geoand it worked.But currently I dont have any idea about root application context and web application context.Diff b/w them. I want to understand the concept.(any helpfull link) what if we have to configure multiple xml files.

Comment: @akash777.sharma Your welcome! You could check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227657/web-application-context-root-application-context-and-transaction-manager-setup or http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/106547-root-application-context-vs-webapplicationcontext